# Calculating Dates Backwards in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I am trying to calculate 6 Fridays before a certain date, as well as 4 Fridays before a certain date, in order to establish deadlines for several departmental responsibilities. I would like the dates to populate in the column beside the initial date. What is a formula that can do this for me?

Comment: I will not give you the readymade formula, but an approach: Excel allows you to get the day of the week as a number. It should be possible to derive a day offset from that, which should give you the last friday. Then simply subtract 28 days to get to your 4 weeks back.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. This is a good question, but for the sake of improving question quality; in the future, please include what you've have already tried or researched to show you've made an effort to find the answer on your own.

Answer (score 1):

This formula should do the trick:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),16)-21
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),16)-35
```

It finds today's date, subtracts how many day are between it and the previous Friday, then subtracts the remaining days until the desired Friday

The `Today()` can also be replaced with the location of the cell which has the initial date

```
=A4-WEEKDAY(A4,16)-21
=A4-WEEKDAY(A4,16)-35
```